# How could this website detect me faking user-agents? or what problems in my codes? (python requests module)

Tags: python, python-requests, user-agent

There are two websites that show user-agent(or HTTP headers). I want to fake them but one try results in a success but the other a failure

1 . http://bei.kr  (results in a failure, showing (maybe)default user-agents of requests module)

2 . http://www.youip.net (results in a success, faked user-agents I made)

```
import requests
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; ko-kr; SAMSUNG 
SM-N900S Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}

res = requests.get('http://bei.kr/',headers=headers) #number 1 url
res.raise_for_status()  
print(res.text)
''' checking the HTTP-header-information contents the site 
shows on the page ; The page shows the following :
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; GT-I9505 Build/LRX22C) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.132 Mobile 
Safari/537.36" '''#Failure #(Maybe)a default user-agent of requests module
```

But the same codes(except for url address) results in a suceess in 'number 2 url'. How could this website('number 1 url') detect me faking user-agents? or what problems in my codes?

Comment: A site may detect a browser by other headers (Accept, Date, etc.) Try to add more headers.

Comment: Is it possible to take 'a real user agent' from other fields of headers(Accept, Date, etc)? How? If I add all fields of headers, can I fake the site (especially in 'User-Agent)?

Comment: Different browsers (and versions) send different sets of headers and values in different orders. If a site wants to protect itself it probably builds a database of headers. Look at what a real browser sends and try to add more headers.

Comment: I see thanks to you. Thanks. But how can I look at what a real brower sends ? After opening bworsers, use 'F12' ? Is it possible not by coding but by manually seeing just with mouse and keyboard?  Or should I make use of Selenium module?

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=detect+browsers+headers

Comment: @JAEWONJUNG You can use Fiddler or Burpsuite to see the request you are sending.  
Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler
BurpSuite: https://portswigger.net/burp/